# How do I output unicode character captured as a substring of command line argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

I am running into some confusion about unicode characters in C++ strings.

I have a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
std::cout << "3rd char of " << argv[1] << "is: " << argv[1][2] <<  std::endl;
}
```

when I run it with this command:

```
 mapper abͲ
```

It returns this:

```
 3rd character of abͲis: �
```

Now, clearly my system supports unicode (Ubuntu 16.04) and the compiler doesn't mind the program (g++ 5.3.1). I understand argv is a vector of char* objects, but how can I access a single character inside a single argument vector if the character is unicode? There must be some type conflict I am missing.

Comment: You have to understand how UTF-8 works.

Comment: @LarryTurtis - suggestion: try to cout `strlen(argv[1])`, `int(argv[1][2])` and `int(argv[1][3])`

Comment: You can't just output individual bytes of a `char*` string without understanding how the bytes have been encoded. In this example, the input character `Ͳ` is actually Unicode codepoint `U+0372 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ARCHAIC SAMPI`, which is encoded in UTF-8 as two bytes `0xCD 0xB2`, which are separate `char` elements in a UTF-8 encoded `char*` string.

Comment: One way to attack these programming problems is to convert input string into UTF-32, which is fixed length per character (= 1 int = 4 bytes), then work with those, or other way is to use some UTF library like `ICU` and it's API functions to pick particular character, length of string (count of characters actually), etc.. For educational purposes it's nice you are trying to handle UTF-8 on your own, but the `ICU` itself is now over 25y old, and it's still being bugfixed and developed... ;)

Comment: And now you may be confused, why UTF-8 has been chosen for linux as default so many times, when it is far from trivial and has this variable bytes per character feature. Answer: most of the time the old command line tools working with ASCII strings (file names mostly) can work with UTF-8 file names without modification, without realising the string was UTF-8 encoded. That's not true with the UTF-16/UCS-2 (Java, Win32) encoding, that one requires all the tools to be changed and recompiled, to be UTF-16/UCS-2 ready.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, this has been very helpful. I did not understand variable-width encoding, but these answers make it clear why it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing to remember when dealing with text in C++ is that one `char` is not equivalent to one character.  For a single-byte character encoding like ASCII one `char` == one character, but for a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8, a character can be composed of multiple `char`s.

In this case, the character you're trying to output (U+0372 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ARCHAIC SAMPI) doesn't fit in a single `char`.  It's actual value will depend on your system text encoding since it's passed into `argv`.  The default encoding on Ubuntu 16.04 is UTF-8, so that character will be the two bytes `0xCD 0xB2`.

Comment: The `char` origin predates back to age of 6 to 8bit encodings (before 7b ASCII become popular and de facto standard). After the computers spread around the world, custom 7-16b encodings were designed for other languages. Unicode-family encodings are quite a new thing from this perspective, happened long time after UNIXes and first file systems, lot of *NIX tools (still used today) did born into fixed 8b encoding environment, locked down to single codepage set for whole system (so a Russians had no chars for korean, etc.). Unicode encodings are modern answer for multi-lang computer usage.

Comment: And UTF-8 is special from Unicode encoding family in the way, that it is partially compatible with ASCII. No zero byte can occur in valid UTF-8 string, unless it's a real zero even in UTF-8 encoding. So for ASCII-ready code the UTF-8 string looks as valid 8 bit extended ASCII zero-terminated string. So as long as the ASCII tool doesn't have to work with letter count or particular character, it will process UTF-8 string correctly. (sorry for so many comments, but I think it's good to understand why these things are done the way they are done :) ).